# Sybase - Creating a test in SQL comparing two columns with strings that have the same substrings but not the same positions

Tags: sql, testing, sybase

The title might be a little hard to comprehend because I'm bad at summarizing things, but what I'm trying to do is actually very simple (in any other language).

I want to test some data in a Sybase table, specifically two columns. These two columns have colon separated strings - and unfortunately, the position of each substring is not the same between both columns. It's something like this:

column_1

> substring1:substring3:substring5
>
> substring2:substring4:substring6

column_2

> substring3:substring1:substring5
>
> substring6:substring2:substring4

What I want to do is provide a simple pass/fail status if substrings of column1 do not equal the substrings of column2. I don't care about the order of the substrings and can't change the order of them before they get to the table. I just want to be able to say:

The test passes if column1 has the same content as column2 regardless of order, and if column1 or column2 contain information that is not present in the other, then it fails.

I could do this blindfolded in something like Python, but I'm not very proficient in SQL. Here's roughly how I'm querying the table:

```
select columna, columnb, columnc, columnd, column_1, column_2, CASE <do tests here> END as test_results from table
```

Any thoughts? I want to keep it a simple as possible ideally!

I now know that each substring will always be exactly 10 characters long, and always be colon separated. However, the number of substrings can vary from 1 - 20 (most will be 2 or 3).

This is Sybase ASE, using RapidSQL 8.6.1, the version of the ADE driver I have installed is 15.07.00.1260 though I don't know much more about our DB setup than that.

Comment: If you know the value of the substrings then you could look into using the SQL Like Operator

Comment: I considered trying to use like. The pseudocode would be something like:
column_2 like '%'+substring(column_1, 1, 10)+'%' - right? or something different?

edit: that doesn't work.

Comment: please update your question with additional details, eg: (per your comment) each substring is 10 characters in length (**exactly** 10 chars?), variable number of substrings?, name of Sybase database software (eg, ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage) and version

Comment: @markp thanks - done.

Comment: @lrossignol: ASE version? (select @@version); I'm thinking you'll need to write a user-defined function, but details will depend on your ASE version

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally following the problem here, specifically if we know the actual length of the strings, if we do, that is great, if we don't the below becomes a bit more difficult.  For now, I assume 10.  Also, I am not sure I follow you column examples, are there carriage returns in the data?  Or was that just a different row?  Anyhow, some code to get you started maybe:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#test') is not null drop table #test
create table #test
(
    column1 varchar(50),
    column2 varchar(50)
)

insert into #test
select 
    'substring1:substing2:substring3',
    'substring3:substring1:substring2'

select
    case 
        when substring(column1,1,charindex(':', column1)-1) = 
                substring(column2,charindex(':', column2)+1, 10)
            then 'pass' 
            else 'fail' 
            end as Substring1Test,

    case 
        when reverse(substring(reverse(column1),1,charindex(':', reverse(column1))-1)  ) =
                substring(column2,1,charindex(':', column2)-1) 
            then 'pass' 
            else 'fail' 
            end as Substring3Test

from #test
```

Comment: The only known fact is that each substring is 10 characters long - it will be variable and it's also worth noting this test is for tens of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase ASE does not have any builtin functions that can perform the desired comparison.

One option available with Sybase ASE 15.0.2+ is the ability to create a user-defined function (UDF).

An example UDF that handles your desired comparison:

```
use sybsystemprocs
go

if object_id('dbo.sp_f_compare') is not NULL
    drop function dbo.sp_f_compare
go

create function dbo.sp_f_compare
(@string1   varchar(300) = NULL
,@string2   varchar(300) = NULL
)
returns varchar(20)
as

declare @source varchar(300),
        @target varchar(300),
        @string varchar(20),
        @pos    smallint,
        @loop   tinyint,
        @result varchar(20)

select  @result = 'pass',
        @loop   = 1,
        @source = @string1,
        @target = ':' + @string2 + ':'

while @loop <= 2
begin
    while @source is not NULL
    begin
        select @pos = charindex(':',@source)

        if @pos = 0 select @pos = 300

        select  @string = ':' + substring(@source,     1,@pos-1) + ':',
                @source =       substring(@source,@pos+1,300   )

        if charindex(@string,@target) = 0
        begin
            select  @result = 'fail'
            break
        end
    end

    if @result = 'fail'
        break

    select  @source = @string2,
            @target = ':' + @string1 + ':',
            @loop   = @loop + 1
end

return @result
go

grant all on dbo.sp_f_compare to public
go
```

NOTES:

- the function name starts with 'sp_' and is installed in the
  sybsytemprocs database; this allows the function to be called from
  any database in the dataserver; otherwise you can name the function
  anything you want and install it in the same database where the data
  (to be compared) resides
- the first pass through the outer loop compares the individual
  components of @string1 against all of @string2; the second pass
  through the loop compares the individual components of @string2
  against all of @string1
- we append a ':' on the ends of the @target string to eliminate the
  need to perform beginning-of-string and end-of-string tests against
  @target

Some sample invocations of the function:

```
declare @string1 varchar(300),
        @string2 varchar(300),
        @string3 varchar(300),
        @string4 varchar(300),
        @string5 varchar(300)

select  @string1 = 'substring1:substring3:substring5',
        @string2 = 'substring3:substring1:substring5',

        @string3 = 'substring2:substring4:substring6',
        @string4 = 'substring6:substring2:substring4',

        @string5 = 'substring2:substring4:substring6:substring7'

select  dbo.sp_f_compare(@string1, @string2) as '1v2',
        dbo.sp_f_compare(@string3, @string4) as '3v4',
        dbo.sp_f_compare(@string1, @string3) as '1v3',
        dbo.sp_f_compare(@string3, @string5) as '3v5',
        dbo.sp_f_compare(@string5, @string3) as '5v3'
go

 1v2        3v4        1v3        3v5        5v3
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 pass       pass       fail       fail       fail
```

NOTES:

- when invoking a UDF you must include the owner of the UDF
  (the 'dbo.' prefix in the above examples)

---

If running Sybase ASE 16 you have access to table @variables.

While you'd still need to create a UDF, said UDF could parse the 2x input strings into table @variables and then run a set-based query against the 2x table @variables to determine 'pass' or 'fail'.

Comment: Thanks for the help. A UDF is a more elegant solution, but for my purposes, it's not very efficient. I simply hard coded individual tests which will be a problem if there's ever more than 4 elements in each column, but for the near term 4 is potentially the max anyways.

Comment: I recommend you post your solution so that others who may stumble upon this Q&A session in the future can see how you solved your problem; of special interest will be how you handle upwards of 20 different substrings (as per your original problem description).

Answer (score 0):

The UDF solution is what I think would be best for something that will be frequently reused. However, for my purposes, the level of effort is just a bit higher than what I want to invest. So I'm skipping a dynamic, clean, efficient, automatic solution and going with a brute force solution that boils down to this logic:
I have two strings I want to compare where any element in any position can exist in any position in the other string (element being a substring of 10 characters separated by a colon). Instead of having a nice loop or anything like that, this is my solution:

```
CASE 
        when substring(batch_ids, 1, 10) = substring(offers,1,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 1, 10) = substring(offers,13,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 1, 10) = substring(offers,24,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 1, 10) = substring(offers,35,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 13, 10) = substring(offers,1,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 13, 10) = substring(offers,13,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 13, 10) = substring(offers,24,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 13, 10) = substring(offers,35,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 24, 10) = substring(offers,1,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 24, 10) = substring(offers,13,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 24, 10) = substring(offers,24,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 24, 10) = substring(offers,35,10) then "PASS"   
        when substring(batch_ids, 35, 10) = substring(offers,1,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 35, 10) = substring(offers,13,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 35, 10) = substring(offers,24,10) then "PASS"
        when substring(batch_ids, 35, 10) = substring(offers,35,10) then "PASS"else "FAIL"
    end as TestResults
```

Essentially, it takes the first element of the first column, substring starting at position 1 and 10 chars long (i.e. 1234567890), and compares that against the substring of the second string in positions 1-10, 13-23, 24-34 and 35-45. It then checks the second substring of the first string against the same set of positions in the second column, and so on. This does mean that if we have a string with more than 4 elements, the maintenance on this would be less than ideal, but the current reality is that we aren't going to see that for a very long time, and this test is only necessary for smoke testing when we do a code change upstream.

While this solution is ugly and inelegant, expansion is a fairly simple copy+paste job and changing a few things here and there.

Edit: I might have the starting positions on some of these wrong but the general gist of my solution is basically does substring of a = substring of b, if so pass, if not then go ahead and fail.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't provide a correct answer, or you've made another change in your req's; your req says to generate `PASS` if both columns contain the same set of substrings (order is not important); your solution will `PASS` as long as **one** substring exists in both column; for example: `batch_ids='substring1:substring2:substring3'`, `offers='substring3:substring4:substring5'` should `FAIL` since they don't contain identical substrings, while your solution will generate a `PASS` because there's at least one match (`substring3`)

Comment: your brute force method's given me an idea for another solution that doesn't require a UDF; I'll post a new answer in a bit ...

Answer (score 0):

While the brute force method proposed by [lrossignol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6489629/lrossignol) won't meet the original requirement (that all substrings must exist in both columns - ordering does not matter), the proposed brute force query has led me to come up with a non-UDF solution ...

---

We'll start by setting up some raw data to test with:

```
use tempdb
go
if object_id('t1') is not NULL
        drop table t1
go
create table t1 (batch_ids varchar(300), offers varchar(300))
go
insert t1 values ('substring1:substring3:substring5',            'substring3:substring1:substring5')
insert t1 values ('substring1:substring2:substring3',            'substring3:substring4:substring5')
insert t1 values ('substring2:substring4:substring6',            'substring6:substring2:substring4')
insert t1 values ('substring1:substring3:substring5',            'substring2:substring4:substring6')
insert t1 values ('substring2:substring4:substring6',            'substring2:substring4:substring6:substring7')
insert t1 values ('substring2:substring4:substring6:substring7', 'substring2:substring4:substring6')
go
```

To eliminate the repetitive coding nature of the brute force solution we can use a table of (starting) indices for use with the substring() calls; while a derived table would likely suffice, I've chosen to use a #temp table to make the coding a little easier to read.

Here's the #indices table and some starting data:

```
if object_id('#indices') is not NULL
        drop table #indices
go
create table #indices (i smallint)
go
-- start with support for 8 substrings; add support for more
-- substrings by adding a new record (+11) for the next index
insert #indices values (1)
insert #indices values (12)
insert #indices values (23)
insert #indices values (34)
insert #indices values (45)
insert #indices values (56)
insert #indices values (67)
insert #indices values (78)
go
```

Instead of testing for all substrings having a match in both columns in order to generate a `PASS`, we just need to find any substring not having a match in the opposite column to generate a `FAIL`.

To reduce the complexity of the string comparisons we'll make sure all strings start and end with a ':' (ie, we don't need special coding for the first and last substrings in a column).

Rolling all of this together gives us the query:

```
select  t1.batch_ids,
        t1.offers,
        case when exists(-- search for each batch_ids substring in offers
                         select  1
                         from    #indices x
                         where   charindex(':'+substring(t1.batch_ids,x.i,10)+':',':'+t1.offers+':') = 0
                         -- only test if we have a substring for index x.i
                         and     substring(t1.batch_ids,x.i,10) is not NULL
                        )
                  or 
                  exists(-- search for each offers substring in batch_ids
                         select  1
                         from    #indices x
                         where   charindex(':'+substring(t1.offers,x.i,10)+':',':'+t1.batch_ids+':') = 0
                         -- only test if we have a substring for index x.i
                         and     substring(t1.offers,x.i,10) is not NULL
                        )
            then 'fail'
            else 'pass'
        end
from    t1
go
```

Results of running the query against our sample data:

```
 batch_ids                                          offers
 -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----
 substring1:substring3:substring5                   substring3:substring1:substring5                   PASS
 substring1:substring2:substring3                   substring3:substring4:substring5                   FAIL
 substring2:substring4:substring6                   substring6:substring2:substring4                   PASS
 substring1:substring3:substring5                   substring2:substring4:substring6                   FAIL
 substring2:substring4:substring6                   substring2:substring4:substring6:substring7        FAIL
 substring2:substring4:substring6:substring7        substring2:substring4:substring6                   FAIL
```